# Time zone detection by city/country name

Tags: php, datetime

Is there any API/data available to detect time zone depending on the provided city/country name?
Like, if I pass a city name, I get the current time zone in this city, if I pass a country name, I get the current time zone in this country's capital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is such thing in PHP. It's named [GeoIP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.geoip.php) - and there is a [geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-time-zone-by-country-and-region.php) function for getting timezone. This works for country/region - so to find timezone by city you will have to link cities and countries. I think it's a task of your application - since in different countries there could be cities with same names (and so it's up to you to decide which country is it and pass it to GeoIP API)

Comment: Why it's not working for china, `geoip_time_zone_by_country_and_region('CN')`, It gives `false`, any idea?